# Scripting theme configuration for a realm

Tags: keycloak

I have made a custom theme for Keycloak and I'd like to set a specific realm to use that theme for the login page and enable internationalization without using admin console, mainly because I want to make it automatic as the realm creation based on the JSON import.

It seems the JSON file is unable to handle theme configuration, is there any way to make this configuration without any human action?

Answer (score 8):

You can use Keycloak CLI to specify a theme for realm. Keycloak CLI executable (`kcadm.bat` or `kcadm.sh`) is placed in the `/bin` directory

First, you need to login with admin credentials:

```
kcadm config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --password ADMIN_PASSWORD
```

Then you need to update corresponding realm, setting its loginTheme attribute:

```
kcadm update realms/REALM_NAME -s "loginTheme=REALM_LOGIN_THEME_NAME"
```